# Dectecting browser with Dojo?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dojo

Can you detect the browser the client is using with dojo? i want to put a function in place if it is IE8.

thanks

Comment: Why are you using browser detection and not *feature* detection, what are you trying to check for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look at

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/browser-sniffing.html

```
if(dojo.isIE == 8){ // only IE8
  ...
}
```